# Insert an array into database using asp.net webservices

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I'm trying to pass an array call dealer to webservices to be inserted into MSSQL 2012 table.

```
<script>
    var dealers = new Array();
    dealers.push(new Array("123", "870503-23-5370", "021"));
    dealers.push(new Array("456", "830503-23-5371", "031"));
    dealers.push(new Array("789", "870103-11-5372", "041"));
    dealers.push(new Array("654", "870501-23-5373", "051"));
    dealers.push(new Array("321", "880503-12-5374", "061"));
    dealers.push(new Array("987", "870803-23-5375", "071"));
    dealers.push(new Array("109", "870508-06-5376", "081"));
    dealers.push(new Array("174", "810503-03-5377", "091"));
    dealers.push(new Array("509", "870103-01-5378", "101"));
    dealers.push(new Array("687", "870501-12-5379", "131"));

    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "Service1.asmx/DailyCheckDealer",
                data: JSON.stringify({ records: dealers }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: onSuccess,
                failure: onError
            });         
        });
    })

    function onSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }

    function onError() {
        alert("fail");
    }
</script>
```

Also I'm still new to ASP.NET VB. Can somebody please help me provide sample code how to process the array and inserted into database.

```
Public Class Service1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function DailyCheckDealer() As String
        "How process the array and inserted into database"
    End Function
End Class
```

Update :

If have change my webservice as below:

```
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function DailyCheckDealer(records As String()()) As String
        Dim mylist As List(Of String()) = records.ToList()
        Dim datarow As String = ""
        Dim result As String = "Done"

        For i As Integer = 0 To mylist.Count - 1
            Dim m As String() = mylist(i)
            For j As Integer = 0 To m.Length - 1
                datarow += m(j) + " "
                Dim objDealer As New Dealer
                Dim myConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MY_CONNECTION")
                Dim myConnection = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
                Dim myCommand = New SqlCommand()
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection
                myCommand.CommandText = "DailyCheckDealer"
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRow", SqlDbType.VarChar, 22).Value = datarow
                myConnection.Open()
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
            Next
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
```

Supposedly it should insert 10 records into database but as for my result it only insert the the first record.

Update:

Sorry my wrong info for result. Whole record was inserted into the database instead of 10 records.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your data layer, pass the json as a string to a stored procedure
2. parse the json string (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/). return as a data table.
3. get the result from step 2 and insert to your table

you will need the 2 db objects below. the first one is a user-defined table type, the second one is the json-parsing stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[typHierarchy] AS TABLE(
    [element_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sequenceNo] [int] NULL,
    [parent_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Object_ID] [int] NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [StringValue] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ValueType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [element_id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)




/*
    taken from https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/
*/

CREATE PROC dbo.spParseJSON
    @strJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)--, @strColumnList VARCHAR(2000)
AS
--SET @strJSON = REPLACE(@strJSON,'\','')

DECLARE @objJSONTable typHierarchy

DECLARE @FirstObject INT, --the index of the first open bracket found in the JSON string
    @OpenDelimiter INT,--the index of the next open bracket found in the JSON string
    @NextOpenDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent open bracket found in the JSON string
    @NextCloseDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent close bracket found in the JSON string
    @Type NVARCHAR(10),--whether it denotes an object or an array
    @NextCloseDelimiterChar CHAR(1),--either a '}' or a ']'
    @Contents NVARCHAR(MAX), --the unparsed contents of the bracketed expression
    @Start INT, --index of the start of the token that you are parsing
    @end INT,--index of the end of the token that you are parsing
    @param INT,--the parameter at the end of the next Object/Array token
    @EndOfName INT,--the index of the start of the parameter at end of Object/Array token
    @token NVARCHAR(200),--either a string or object
    @value NVARCHAR(MAX), -- the value as a string
    @SequenceNo int, -- the sequence number within a list
    @name NVARCHAR(200), --the name as a string
    @parent_ID INT,--the next parent ID to allocate
    @lenJSON INT,--the current length of the JSON String
    @characters NCHAR(36),--used to convert hex to decimal
    @result BIGINT,--the value of the hex symbol being parsed
    @index SMALLINT,--used for parsing the hex value
    @Escape INT --the index of the next escape character                                                                                     

DECLARE @Strings TABLE /* in this temporary table we keep all strings, even the names of the elements, since they are 'escaped' in a different way, and may contain, unescaped, brackets denoting objects or lists. These are replaced in the JSON string by tokens representing the string */
    (String_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT--initialise the characters to convert hex to ascii
    @characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    @SequenceNo=0, --set the sequence no. to something sensible.
    /* firstly we process all strings. This is done because [{} and ] aren't escaped in strings, which complicates an iterative parse. */
    @parent_ID=0;

WHILE 1=1 --forever until there is nothing more to do
BEGIN
        SELECT @start=PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]["]%', @strJSON collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);--next delimited string

        IF @start=0 BREAK --no more so drop through the WHILE loop

        IF SUBSTRING(@strJSON, @start+1, 1)='"'
        BEGIN --Delimited Name
            SET @start=@Start+1;
            SET @end=PATINDEX('%[^\]["]%', RIGHT(@strJSON, LEN(@strJSON+'|')-@start) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);
        END

        IF @end=0 --no end delimiter to last string
            BREAK --no more

        SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(@strJSON, @start+1, @end-1)

        --now put in the escaped control characters
        SELECT @token=REPLACE(@token, FROMString, TOString)
        FROM
            (SELECT '\"' AS FromString, '"' AS ToString
                UNION ALL SELECT '\\', '\'
                UNION ALL SELECT '\/', '/'
                UNION ALL SELECT '\b', CHAR(08)
                UNION ALL SELECT '\f', CHAR(12)
                UNION ALL SELECT '\n', CHAR(10)
                UNION ALL SELECT '\r', CHAR(13)
                UNION ALL SELECT '\t', CHAR(09)) substitutions

        SELECT @result=0, @escape=1

        --Begin to take out any hex escape codes
        WHILE @escape>0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @index=0,
                --find the next hex escape sequence
                @escape=PATINDEX('%\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)

            IF @escape>0 --IF there is one
            BEGIN
                WHILE @index<4 --there are always four digits to a \x sequence  
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT --determine its value
                            @result=@result+POWER(16, @index)
                            *(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@token, @escape+2+3-@index, 1),
                            @characters)-1), @index=@index+1 ;
                    END

                -- and replace the hex sequence by its unicode value
                SELECT @token=STUFF(@token, @escape, 6, NCHAR(@result))
            END
        END

        --now store the string away
        INSERT INTO @Strings (StringValue) SELECT @token

        -- and replace the string with a token
        SELECT @strJSON=STUFF(@strJSON, @start, @end+1,
            '@string'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @@identity))
    END

    -- all strings are now removed. Now we find the first leaf. 
    WHILE 1=1  --forever until there is nothing more to do
    BEGIN
        SELECT @parent_ID=@parent_ID+1

        --find the first object or list by looking for the open bracket
        SELECT @FirstObject=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%', @strJSON collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object or array

        IF @FirstObject = 0 BREAK

        IF (SUBSTRING(@strJSON, @FirstObject, 1)='{')
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
        ELSE
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'

        SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@firstObject

        WHILE 1=1 --find the innermost object or list...
        BEGIN
            SELECT @lenJSON=LEN(@strJSON+'|')-1

            --find the matching close-delimiter proceeding after the open-delimiter
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiter=CHARINDEX(@NextCloseDelimiterChar, @strJSON,
                @OpenDelimiter+1)

            --is there an intervening open-delimiter of either type
            SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%',
                RIGHT(@strJSON, @lenJSON-@OpenDelimiter)collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object

            IF @NextOpenDelimiter=0 BREAK

            SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter+@OpenDelimiter

            IF @NextCloseDelimiter<@NextOpenDelimiter BREAK

            IF SUBSTRING(@strJSON, @NextOpenDelimiter, 1)='{'
                SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
            ELSE
                SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'

            SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter
        END

    ---and parse out the list or name/value pairs
    SELECT @contents=SUBSTRING(@strJSON, @OpenDelimiter+1,
        @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter-1)

    SELECT @strJSON=STUFF(@strJSON, @OpenDelimiter,
        @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter+1,
        '@'+@type+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @parent_ID))

    WHILE (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin))<>0
    BEGIN
        IF @Type='Object' --it will be a 0-n list containing a string followed by a string, number,boolean, or null
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SequenceNo=0,@end=CHARINDEX(':', ' '+@contents)--IF there is anything, it will be a string-based name.

            SELECT  @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z@][@]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--AAAAAAAA

            SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(' '+@contents, @start+1, @End-@Start-1),
                @endofname=PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin),
                @param=RIGHT(@token, LEN(@token)-@endofname+1)

            SELECT @token=LEFT(@token, @endofname-1),
                @Contents=RIGHT(' '+@contents, LEN(' '+@contents+'|')-@end-1)

            SELECT  @name=stringvalue FROM @strings WHERE string_id=@param --fetch the name
        END
        ELSE
            SELECT @Name=null,@SequenceNo=@SequenceNo+1

        SELECT @end=CHARINDEX(',', @contents)-- a string-token, object-token, list-token, number,boolean, or null

        --for debugging|start
        --SELECT [@startxxx] = @start
        --for debugging|end

        IF @end=0
            SELECT  @end=PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e][^A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @Contents+' ' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin) + 1

        --include negative values|start
        --SELECT @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9@+.e][A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', ' ' + @contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
        SELECT @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9@+.e][A-Za-z0-9@+.e][^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$]%', ' ' + @contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
        --include negative values|end

        --for debugging|start
        --SELECT [@value] = @value, [@Contents] = @Contents, [@start] = @start
        --for debugging|end

        --select @start,@end, LEN(@contents+'|'), @contents 
        SELECT @Value=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @End-@Start)),
            @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)

        IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@object'
            INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
            SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5), SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5), 'object'
        ELSE
            IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 6)='@array'
                INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
                SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5), SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5), 'array'
            ELSE
                IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@string'
                    INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                    SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, stringvalue, 'string'
                    FROM @strings
                    WHERE string_id=SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5)
                ELSE
                    IF @value IN ('true', 'false')
                        INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'boolean'
                    ELSE
                        IF @value='null'
                            INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                            SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'null'
                        ELSE
                            IF PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)>0
                            --BEGIN
                                INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                                SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'real'

                                --for debugging|start
                                --SELECT [@value] = @value, [@Contents] = @Contents
                                --for debugging|end
                            --END
                            ELSE
                                INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                                SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'int'

        IF @Contents=' ' SELECT @SequenceNo=0
    END
END

INSERT INTO @objJSONTable (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
SELECT '-',1, NULL, '', @parent_id-1, @type

--for debugging|start
--SELECT 'R E T U R N', * FROM @objJSONTable
--for debugging|end

DELETE h
FROM @objJSONTable h
WHERE h.NAME = '-'

--for debugging|start
--SELECT 'after delete', * FROM @objJSONTable
--for debugging|end

--SELECT *
--INTO #tbl
--FROM dbo.udfSplitString(@strColumnList)

SELECT ID = t.NAME
INTO #tbl
FROM @objJSONTable t

--for debugging|start
--SELECT '#tbl', t.* FROM #tbl t
--for debugging|end

DECLARE @strCurrentColumn VARCHAR(100)
    , @strSQLColumn VARCHAR(1000)
    --, @strSQL VARCHAR(2000) = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT h.NAME, h.StringValue FROM @objJSONTable h) a PIVOT(MAX(StringValue) FOR NAME IN (*columnNamesHere*)) AS p'
    , @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT h.NAME, h.StringValue FROM @objJSONTable h) a PIVOT(MAX(StringValue) FOR NAME IN (*columnNamesHere*)) AS p'

--for debugging|start
--SELECT [@strSQL] = @strSQL
--for debugging|end

SELECT TOP 1 @strCurrentColumn = t.ID
FROM #tbl t

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    --for debugging|start
    --SELECT CONCAT('loop all columns >>> ', @strCurrentColumn)
    --for debugging|end

    SET @strSQLColumn = CONCAT(@strSQLColumn, '[', @strCurrentColumn, '], ')

    DELETE #tbl
    WHERE ID = @strCurrentColumn

    SELECT TOP 1 @strCurrentColumn = t.ID
    FROM #tbl t
END --WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

SET @strSQLColumn = LEFT(@strSQLColumn, LEN(@strSQLColumn) - 1)
SET @strSQL = REPLACE(@strSQL, '*columnNamesHere*', @strSQLColumn)

--for debugging|start
--SELECT [@strSQLColumn] = @strSQLColumn, [@strSQL] = @strSQL
DROP TABLE #tbl
--for debugging|end

DECLARE @strParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

SET @strParmDefinition = N'@objJSONTable typHierarchy READONLY'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @strSQL, @strParmDefinition
    , @objJSONTable = @objJSONTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature you're looking for should be:

```
<ScriptMethod> _
<WebMethod()> _        
Public Function DailyCheckDealer(dealers As String()()) As String
   ' insert to db here
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```

However it is usually better to have strongly typed object instead of array.

```
<script>
    var dealers = new Array();
    dealers.push({ ID: "123", Phone: "870503-23-5370", Code: "021"));
    ...
</script>
```

VB code:

```
Public Class Dealer
Public Property ID() As String
    Get
        Return m_ID
    End Get
    Set
        m_ID = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_ID As String
Public Property Code() As String
    Get
        Return m_Code
    End Get
    Set
        m_Code = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Code As String
Public Property Phone() As String
    Get
        Return m_Phone
    End Get
    Set
        m_Phone = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Phone As String
End Class    

<WebService> _
<ScriptService> _
Public Class Service1
  Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

  <ScriptMethod> _
  <WebMethod> _
  Public Function DailyCheckDealer(dealers As Dealer()) As String
      ' insert to db here
      Return String.Empty
  End Function
End Class
```

Also the WebServices are hopelessly outdated nowadays - if you can I recommend creating WEB API controller instead (http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/quick-start-scenarios/asp.net-web-api/quickstart-webapi-create-api-controllers) or if you're stick to .NET 3.5 framework WCF service.

Comment: Thank for replied. In the webmethod, how am I going to process (loop) on each record so I could write into database.